# How to place these algorithms side by side in a special way

Tags: formatting, algorithms, algorithm2e

I have the following problem:
I want to place to algorithms side by side such that the lines with the same number are on the same height. Unfortunately, until now it looks like that
[image].

What I do not like about that is that they both take much less space than what would be available (which most likely is due to my incompetence with \setstretch), that the lines are often broken at a bad point and that the lines are not synchronized (sucht that line number one from the left algorithm and line number one from the right algorithm are on the same height and next to each other.
Would anybody be so kind to help me fix it?
Thanks in advance! The MWE is below

MWE:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
    \usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    
        \begin{document}
        \begin{frame}[t]{}
            \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \scalebox{.7}{
                    \SetAlgoNoLine
                    \begin{algorithm}[H]
                        \setstretch{0.7}
                        \Input{$ S = (S_+, S_-) $}
                        \Output{DFA $ \mathcal{A}(S) $}
                        %                       \Output{DFA $ \mathcal{A} $ which is consistent with $ S $}
                        \BlankLine
                        $ T := PTA(S_+) $\; % noch abändern zu passender Definition
                        $ \sim := \{(u,u) | u \in Q_+\} $\;
                        \For{$ w \in Pref(S_+) $ in llex-order}{
                            \If{$ w \not\sim v $ for all $ v <_{llex} w $}{\label{RPNI-if-check}
                                \For {$ \{v \in S_+ | v <_{llex} w \} $ in llex order}{
                                    $ \sim_{test} :=  $ smallest congruence containing $ \sim $ and $ (v, w) $\;
                                    $ \mathcal{B} := \mathcal{A}(S_+)/\sim_{test} $\;
                                    \If{$ L(\mathcal{B}) \cap S_- = \emptyset $}{
                                        $ \sim := \sim_{test} $\;
                                        GoTo line \ref{rpni-e-exitInnerFor}\;
                                        %exit inner for-loop\;
                                    }
                                }\label{rpni-e-exitInnerFor}
                            }
                        }
                    \Return{$\mathcal{A} := (T, F)$ }\;
                        \caption{RPNI on llex-order}\label{RPNI-eigenFormal}
                    \end{algorithm}
                }
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \scalebox{.7}{
                    \SetAlgoNoLine
                    \begin{algorithm

}[H]
                    \setstretch{0.7}
                    \Input{$S = (S_+, S_-) $}
                    %$ S_+ \neq \emptyset $ eigentlich nicht nötig, wenn man als Automaten, der alles abweist den \varepsilon-Automat sieht
                    \Output{DFA $ \mathcal{A}(S) $}
                    %\Output{DFA $ \mathcal{A} $ which is consistent with $ S $}
                    \BlankLine
                    $ Q := \{\varepsilon\} $; $ \delta := \emptyset $; $ q_0 := \varepsilon $; $ T := (Q, \Sigma, \varepsilon, \delta) $;\\
                    \While {$ Escapes(S_+, T) $}{\label{sprLL-while}
                        $ ua := min_{llex}(Escapes(Pref(S_+), T)) $\;
                        \For {$ \{v | v < w \land v \in S_+\} $ in llex order}{                             
                            \If{$ IsConsistent (T + (\delta^*(u), a, \delta^*(v)), S) $} {
                                $ \delta := \delta \cup \{(\delta^*(u), a, \delta^*(v))\} $\;
                                KwGoTo while (line \ref{sprLL-while})
                            }
                        }
                        
                        $ Q := Q \cup \{ua\} $\;
                        $ \delta :=  \delta \cup \{(\delta^*(u), a, ua)\}$\;
                    }
                    $ F := ComputeAcc (T, S) $\;
                    \Return{$\mathcal{A} := (T, F)$ }\;
                    \caption{Sprout on llex-order}\label{SprG-llex}
                \end{algorithm}
            }
        \end{minipage}
        
    \end{frame} 
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Typically algorithm packages ignore standard spacing and alignment rules.  If your package supports inline coding, try paracol and \switchcolumn*.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, it is still not looking pretty

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `\scalebox` for things which contain text. Instead choose a suitable font size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\scriptsize}
\renewcommand\AlCapNameFnt{\AlCapFnt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
  \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
      \centering
          \scriptsize
          \SetAlgoNoLine
          \begin{algorithm}[H]
              \setstretch{0.7}
              \Input{$ S = (S_+, S_-) $}
              \Output{DFA $ \mathcal{A}(S) $}
                                     \Output{DFA $ \mathcal{A} $ which is consistent with $ S $}
              \BlankLine
              $ T := PTA(S_+) $\; % noch abändern zu passender Definition
              $ \sim := \{(u,u) | u \in Q_+\} $\;
              \For{$ w \in Pref(S_+) $ in llex-order}{
                  \If{$ w \not\sim v $ for all $ v <_{llex} w $}{\label{RPNI-if-check}
                      \For {$ \{v \in S_+ | v <_{llex} w \} $ in llex order}{
                          $ \sim_{test} :=  $ smallest congruence containing $ \sim $ and $ (v, w) $\;
                          $ \mathcal{B} := \mathcal{A}(S_+)/\sim_{test} $\;
                          \If{$ L(\mathcal{B}) \cap S_- = \emptyset $}{
                              $ \sim := \sim_{test} $\;
                              GoTo line \ref{rpni-e-exitInnerFor}\;
                              %exit inner for-loop\;
                          }
                      }\label{rpni-e-exitInnerFor}
                  }
              }
          \Return{$\mathcal{A} := (T, F)$ }\;
              \caption{RPNI on llex-order}\label{RPNI-eigenFormal}
          \end{algorithm}
  \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
          \centering
              \SetAlgoNoLine
              \scriptsize
              \begin{algorithm}[H]
              \setstretch{0.7}
              \Input{$S = (S_+, S_-) $}
              %$ S_+ \neq \emptyset $ eigentlich nicht nötig, wenn man als Automaten, der alles abweist den \varepsilon-Automat sieht
              \Output{DFA $ \mathcal{A}(S) $}
              %\Output{DFA $ \mathcal{A} $ which is consistent with $ S $}
              \BlankLine
              $ Q := \{\varepsilon\} $; $ \delta := \emptyset $; $ q_0 := \varepsilon $; $ T := (Q, \Sigma, \varepsilon, \delta) $;\\
              \While {$ Escapes(S_+, T) $}{\label{sprLL-while}
                  $ ua := min_{llex}(Escapes(Pref(S_+), T)) $\;
                  \For {$ \{v | v < w \land v \in S_+\} $ in llex order}{                             
                      \If{$ IsConsistent (T + (\delta^*(u), a, \delta^*(v)), S) $} {
                          $ \delta := \delta \cup \{(\delta^*(u), a, \delta^*(v))\} $\;
                          KwGoTo while (line \ref{sprLL-while})
                      }
                  }
                  
                  $ Q := Q \cup \{ua\} $\;
                  $ \delta :=  \delta \cup \{(\delta^*(u), a, ua)\}$\;
              }
              $ F := ComputeAcc (T, S) $\;
              \Return{$\mathcal{A} := (T, F)$ }\;
              \caption{Sprout on llex-order}\label{SprG-llex}
          \end{algorithm}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]